# How to retrieve data from MS Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to fetch data from excel using below C# code. I am getting the value from two 
 columns into single variable(str).

I want that value into different variables.So that i can send that value at runtime for  two different statements.

How to bring them into two different variable?

```
 string currentSheet = "Sheet1";

        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        //Opening/adding Excel file
        excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(workbookPath);
        excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Sheets;
        excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

        //Gives the used cells in the sheet
        range = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;

        for (rowCnt = 1; rowCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
        {
            for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= range.Rows.Count;colCnt++)
            {
                str = (string)(range.Cells[rowCnt,colCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                System.Console.WriteLine(str);
             }

        }
```

Comment: First of all I think that you should iterate the second loop over `Columns.Count`. Second what is this `Value2` function and does it return? Also include the name of the library you are using for manipulating Excel files.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library for manipulating Excel. and Value2 is the dynamic variable returning the range of objectRangeValueDataType.

Answer (score 1):

```
  string Connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Connection);

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);

        myCommand.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
```

Comment: What asieh is trying to say is that retrieving data from an Excel sheet is a far better solution than using Interop (performance and compatibility).

Comment: I just want to get the value in different variables

Answer (score 0):

```
for (rowCnt = 1; rowCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
        {

            string Charity = (string)(range.Cells[rowCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value; 
            string Country = (string)(range.Cells[rowCnt, 2] as Excel.Range).Value; 
            System.Console.WriteLine(Charity + " --- " + Country);

        }
```

Comment: If that is the problem solving solution, so MARK IT AS ANSWERED!